# Grothendieck's quote about the importance of ideas

Tags: soft-question, math-history, mathematicians

In short, I think I've seen somewhere in the literature where Grothendieck similarly said,

> What I feel when I do math is that idea is important."

Or, I think I saw that

> More important than proof is an idea and, even furthermore dream.

But I forgot where I saw it. Now I can't find the exact source involved. Récoltes et Semailles? La clef des songes?  Can anyone guess or tell me the exact data in this regard? :)

Comment: Is it this: Grothendieck's most popular quote on the Internet:
“_If there is one thing in mathematics that fascinates me more than anything else (and doubtless always has), it is neither "number" nor "size", but always form. And among the thousand-and-one faces whereby form chooses to reveal itself to us, the one that fascinates me more than any other and continues to fascinate me, is the structure hidden in mathematical things._”
Full text:
A. Grothendieck. Récoltes et Semailles.?

Comment: Yes. I saw the quote too~ Uhm It looks different from that I mentioned. Anyway thank you~

Comment: I chose to suggest this because: (1) There is emphasis on something being _more_ than something else, just like you recollect. (2) The source matches your first choice.  Nothing. Just explaining myself.

Comment: O.K. I got it. Thanks~~ :)

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grothendieck

Comment: O.K. Thanks for link~~!

Comment: If no one answers till Saturday, consider reposting at HSM SE (with a link to this question).

Comment: O.K. Thanks for comment.~